# Inject JavaScript from async method in generic handler

Tags: asynchronous, httphandler, restsharp

In my generic handler I perform an asynchronous HTTP POST using RestSharp and then display some html to the user before waiting for the POST request to come back. Then once the Http Response comes back I would like to display a message by injecting some Javascript.

```
var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {
       if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
       {
           //here I would like to display a notification to the user but the handler already returned processedHtml at this point
           context.Response.Write(@"<script type='text/javascript'>
                                                window.parent.$.gritter.add({
                                                    text: 'some message',
                                                    time: 20000,
                                                    sticky: false
                                                });</script>");
       }
    });

//this line executes before waiting for response from async call
context.Response.Write(processedHtml);
```

The problem is that at that point the lifecycle is over so context.Response.Write(@"<script ... ") generates "Object reference not set to instance of an object". Is there any other way to inject javascript when the async response comes back?

Comment: Ummm, of course that line executes, you did a asynchronous call, so nothing waits for that code. That is the definition. Why don't you have a function called when the asynch call is completed?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do; however, at that point the handler had already completed its lifecycle, so I can't inject any Javascript using context.Response.Write.

Comment: You could using something like JQuery's $.ajax function which allows you to set a function to be called with the results upon completion. Otherwise, search the Javascript documentation for something similar.